# submit form in code igniter via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i want to submit a form via ajax but i dnt know why form is not submiting via ajax. why ajax not picking the submit id..this code just submitting as usual way but not through ajax
help me where i am wrong ..

```
 echo form_open('Contact_Controller/submit');
 echo form_input('name', set_value('name'), 'id="name"');
 echo form_input('email', set_value('email'), 'id="email"');
 $data = array(
        'name'=> 'message',
        'id' => 'message',
        'cols'=> '35',
        'rows' => '12'

        );
 echo form_textarea($data, 'Message');
 echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit', 'id="submit"');
 ?>
```

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function(){

var form_data = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        message: $('#message').val()
};

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('tuts_Contact_Controller/submit'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: either use `e.preventDefault();` or `return false;`

Answer (score 6):

Use this way:

and i am guessing that you are having jquery above this script.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function(){       // <----------------missed the doc ready function
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // <------this will restrict the page refresh
    var form_data = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        message: $('#message').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('tuts_Contact_Controller/submit'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data, // $(this).serialize(); you can use this too
        success: function(msg) {
              alert(msg);
        }

   });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanksssssssssss it works

Answer (score 1):

you should prevent the default event of form submit like:

```
$('#submit').click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  ....
```

Comment: do you see any error in console ..?